# Pandas : Performing an operation using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
df1 = 

                        A     B     C      D       E       F 
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00     40    50    NaN    50     NaN    NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:01     70    80    80     10     NaN    NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:02     200   220   NaN    10     10     NaN


df2 = 

             A_1       B_1    
                
C            10        10
D            20        10   
E            30        20 
F            5         15
```

As you can see, the `columns` C,D,E and F of `df1` are `index` of `df2`. I want to perform an operation as follows:
For each row in `df1`, the values in columns C D E and F are checked. If there is a value present in one of the columns, the name of the column is noted. Then the corresponding values for `columns A and B` are taken. These values are added with the values in A_1 and B_1 of `df2` for that particular index (which was noted earlier) and this sum is updated back in `df1`. The below table might explain the problem better. The expected output is as follows:

```
df1 = 

                        A     B     C      D       E       F    Sum_C  Sum_D   Sum_E   Sum_F
timestamp               
2022-04-08 10:07:00     40    50    NaN    50     NaN    NaN    NaN    120     NaN     NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:01     70    80    80     10     NaN    NaN   170     180     NaN     NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:02     200   220   NaN    10     10     NaN    NaN    450     470     NaN
```

Here,

In the first row of `df1`, there is a value for `column D`. The values from `column A and B` are 40 and 50. Now, since there is a value present in `column D` of `df1`, the index D of `df2` is selected, the corresponding A_1 and B_1 is noted which in this case is 20 and 10.
All of these values (A + B + A_1 + B_1) is added resulting in a value of 120. This is added in `Sum_D` column of `df1`. The rest of the values (`Sum_C`,`Sum_E`,`Sum_F`) are `NaN`.

Would appreciate if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Instead of adding the values obtained from columns A,B,A_1,B_1, I would like to do the following:

```
import geopy.distance as distance
P1 = (A,B)
P2 = (A_1,B_1)
```

Calculate the distance using `distance.great_circle(P1,P2)` and store this result in `df1`.
So in the columns `Sum_C`,`Sum_D`,`Sum_E` and `Sum_F`, instead of adding the values A + B + A_1 + B_1, I would like to do the above operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
d = df1[df2.index].notna()
out = (df1
       .join(d.mul(df2.sum(1)) # add sum from df2
              .add(df1[['A', 'B']].sum(1), axis=0) # add data from A/B
              .where(d)                            # keep only original non-NAN
              .add_prefix('Sum_')
            )
       )
```

output:

```
                       A    B     C   D     E   F  Sum_C  Sum_D  Sum_E  Sum_F
timestamp                                                                    
2022-04-08 10:07:00   40   50   NaN  50   NaN NaN    NaN    120    NaN    NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:01   70   80  80.0  10   NaN NaN  170.0    180    NaN    NaN
2022-04-08 10:07:02  200  220   NaN  10  10.0 NaN    NaN    450  470.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! In this case, its just calculating sum. But If I have to perform a bit advanced mathematical operation, how do I alter this?

Comment: Well, hard to know without more details. This could be an easy change or a completely different strategy... Maybe this should be a follow up question?

Comment: Well, its just a small operation using the geopy.distance and I have mentioned it in the edit.

Comment: then it might be more tricky, probably worth asking a separate question with all the relevant details

Comment: Provided all the relevant details in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200861/performing-an-operation-using-two-dataframes-using-pandas